# Github Gists syntax highlight is not working

Tags: github, gist

I am trying to create a gist with Markdown syntax highlight. Unfortunately can't post a screenshot here.

Then I press 'save' and get no syntax highlight applied.
The same issue is there with Python code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution:

You need to place a proper file extension for the filename you are trying to save, for example

```
Python RegEx
```

should become

```
Python RegEx.md
```

Spaces are ignored.

Answer (score 24):

You need to change the file extension to `.md`

Here's my fork of your [gist](https://gist.github.com/swarajgiri/7c73ef288023001486a4)

Answer (score 7):

You have to add an extension for *your* language. Add .py *not* .md if you want python highlighting.

Comment: Is there a reference document for which extensions map to which language highlighting?